# behaviour of function parameters in c programming

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters, behavior

So I was casually doing my usual theory proving code (testing things with code) and those code differences really got me thinking

```
#include <stdio.h>
int mutate(int a){
a+=1;
printf("%d\n", a);
}
void main(){
int b = 1;
mutate(b);
printf("%d", b);
}
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>
int mutate(int *a){
*a+=1;
printf("%d\n", *a);
}
void main(){
int b = 1;
mutate(&b);
printf("%d", b);
}
```

Why in the first code there's a change without pointers in the first place.? Why there is a temporary change? The code with pointers I already understand though. Could someone explain though?

Comment: In the first sample, you actually edit the local copy which is valid within the functions scope.

Comment: Firstly your 1st function should be returning integer but it is not returning anything and this code will not compile

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea It will probably just produce a warning, but it is undefined anyways.

Comment: @alex01011 okay

Comment: It's actually *not* UB since the return value of the function is never used.

Comment: those functions work perfectly what are you guys talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use two different ways to pass parameters.

The first implementation of the `mutate` function uses **call by value** where a copy of the input parameter is created on the stack which is locally modified as you see in your print result. The value of the original input variable remains unmodified.

The second uses **call by reference** where a reference to the input variable is given and hence the input variable's value gets modified.

For a nice explanation see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy, it also contains the following example which is extremely close to what you are doing:

```c
void modify(int p, int* q, int* r) {
    p = 27; // passed by value: only the local parameter is modified
    *q = 27; // passed by value or reference, check call site to determine which
    *r = 27; // passed by value or reference, check call site to determine which
}

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int x = 1;
    int* c = &x;
    modify(a, &b, c); // a is passed by value, b is passed by reference by creating a pointer (call by value),
                    // c is a pointer passed by value
                    // b and x are changed
    return 0;
}
```

Now your example with output:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void mutate1(int a) {
    a+=1;
    printf("value of a inside mutate1:  %d\n", a);
}

void mutate2(int *a){
    *a+=1;
    printf("value of *a inside mutate2: %d\n", *a);
}

int main(){
    int b = 1;
    printf("value of b before mutate1:  %d\n", b);
    mutate1(b);
    printf("value of b after mutate1:   %d\n\n", b);

    b = 1;
    printf("value of b before mutate2:  %d\n", b);
    mutate2(&b);
    printf("value of b after mutate2:   %d\n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall mutate.c
$ ./a.out           
value of b before mutate1:  1
value of a inside mutate1:  2
value of b after mutate1:   1

value of b before mutate2:  1
value of *a inside mutate2: 2
value of b after mutate2:   2
$
```

As can be observed `b` does not get modified when using **call by value** but it does when using **call by reference**.

Comment: oh okay so in the mutate1 the value of b is copied to the parameter and that is a's new value. But why is it that if you use pointer in function then the asterisk has to be next to the variable name all the time inside a function. If you're using pointers in main function then you don't have to use asterisk next to pointer's name all the time. why is it?

Comment: Due to `int *a` `a` is a pointer to an `int`. `*a` dereferences the pointer and represents the value `a` points to, i.e. the actual integer value. `*a+=1;` or in explicit form `*a = *a + 1;` means read the value at position `a`, increase it by one and store it in position `a`.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator